# Read two .TIF files from an .IMG file

Tags: vb.net, binaryreader

Dealing with some legacy code that parses .TIF images (front and back images for checks) from an .IMG file. For example, I have the following file: 05090001.IMG and then I have the following values about that file:

FrontStart: 8 | FrontLength: 10600 | RearStart: 10608 | RearLength: 6372

The size of 05090001.IMG is 16980 bytes, so it seems that the front image should be 10600 bytes and does in fact create a valid .TIF file while the rear image always ends up corrupt.

This is the existing code that retrieves the front .TIF file:

```
Dim fs As New FileStream(Me.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim sr As New BinaryReader(fs)
Dim fname As String = {long formula to generate fname}

Dim fsFront As New FileStream(fname & "_Front.tif", FileMode.Create)
Dim swFront As New BinaryWriter(fsFront)
Dim imgBytesFront As Byte()

fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(DownImageFiles, dr("ImgFile")), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
sr = New BinaryReader(fs)
imgBytesFront = sr.ReadBytes(dr("FrontLength"))

swFront.Write(imgBytesFront)
swFront.Close()
fsFront.Close()
```

I'm trying to add similar code to access the rear image file:

```
Dim fsRear As New FileStream(fname & "_Rear.tif", FileMode.Create)
Dim swRear As New BinaryWriter(fsRear)
Dim imgBytesRear As Byte()

fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(DownImageFiles, dr("ImgFile")), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
    br.BaseStream.Seek(Long.Parse(dr("FrontLength"), Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer), SeekOrigin.Begin)
    imgBytesRear = br.ReadBytes(dr("RearLength"))
End Using

imgBytesRear = sr.ReadBytes(dr("RearLength"))
swRear.Write(imgBytesRear)
swRear.Close()
fsRear.Close()
```

This generates an image, but Windows says it is "damaged, corrupted, or is too large".

Any ideas what I'm missing? Am I using the Seek method properly? Am I somehow reading the first 6372 bytes again instead of skipping the first 10600 and starting there? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Difficult to help that much without having the data, but I would strongly suggest that you refactor this into one function that returns a byte array based on the filedata and start and end values, then if one works they both work (or should)

Comment: Thanks. And agreed. But do the br.BaseStream.Seek and subsequent br.ReadBytes calls in the rear image section seem like they would seek to and then read  correctly?

Comment: One diagnostic you can try is to look at the "rear" file you created.  The first two bytes should be either be 0x4949 or 0x4D4D.  If it doesn't start with that, you're not reading from the right spot.

Comment: Thanks! So, I opened both the front and rear images in Sublime and the front starts with 4949 while the rear starts with 978f. I also opened the .IMG file and did a find for 4949 and only found the one at the very beginning. I'm not familiar with the 4949/4D4D codes. Does that make it seem there may not be a second image or will Sublime just not search like that (though, it finds the first one).

Comment: All TIF files start with 0x49494 ("II") or 0x4D4D ("MM") to indicate Endianess of the rest of the file.  II means "Intel", MM means Motorola.  One feature of a TIF file is that you can have multiple images (i.e. pages) in it, although there is only one "II" or "MM" in the entire file.

Comment: I accidentally discovered that simply renaming the .IMG file to .TIF results in a 2-page TIF (I didn't know that was a thing). So, pivoting to look for code to split that. May have something.

Comment: "I accidentally discovered that simply renaming the .IMG file to .TIF results in a 2-page TIF".  Have you tried loading the file into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, calling `SelectActiveFrame(Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, pgNum) and saving the image?

Comment: I've written Java code to extract selected pages from a multi-page TIFF using the JAI library.  That probably isn't too helpful for VB, except to know that it's possible and it might be something to look at for ideas.

Comment: @TnTinMn - Thanks! Yeah, that is essentially what I ended up doing. From here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Split-multi-page-tiff-file-058050cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to several people in the comments above, I found that simply loading the .IMG file in as a System.Drawing.Image, I could then split it into individual page files.

```
Dim tiffCheck As Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(DownImageFiles, dr("ImgFile")))
```

After that, I essentially followed the solution under the Split() function here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Split-multi-page-tiff-file-058050cc

Comment: Yeah, but it won't let me for 2 days because it's my own answer. I'll definitely try to remember to do that tomorrow.